# What happens with ID when 1 object from table in database is moved and its ID is set on auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I've made table in database so that user can put objects in database which ID will be automatically increased. Let's say that user wants to move object from database after some time while already more objects are added in database. Will this now not covered number of ID be covered during next filling of database with object?

Comment: Downvote: why dont you just try and see what happens, or type the question in a search engine?

Comment: What does "move object from database" mean? Do you mean _delete_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will keep the count as was it before